# invoke-command $list .\script.ps1 -asjob, many child jobs stay at 'notstarted' status

Tags: powershell, jobs, invoke-command

Here's an example script:

```
sleep 3600
```

If I run it like this on a group of computers, a lot of them stay at 'notstarted' status:

```
$list = cat hps.txt # 190 computers
invoke-command $list .\script.ps1 -asjob

sleep 60; job -includechildjob | ? state -eq notstarted  # 157 not started
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `ThrottleLimit` parameter on [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6);

It limits how many concurrent connections `Invoke-Command` will open at one time; the default is 32, which looks like what you're running into (190 - 32 = 158).

Comment: You're right.  I didn't think throttlelimit applied to the number of *finished jobs*.